# Create new range from 3 other column ranges in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 ranges in VBA:

```
range1 = Range("A:A")
range2 = Range("B:B")
range3 = Range("C:C")
```

i want to return a new range where each row in the three ranges are added together.

So if I have the data

```
A, B, C
=========
1, 2, 3
2, 4, 5
1, 1, 2
```

where each of the 3 ranges only consist of the values (the column names are just to explain). So the first range has values 1, 2, 1, the second range has values 2, 4, 1, and the third range has values 3, 5, 2.

I want to output the range consisting of

```
6
11
4
```

I guess it is something like

```
Dim newRange As Range
Dim RowNo    As Long

// make newRange as long as one of the other ranges

For Each RowNo in LBound(newRange)
    newRange(RowNo).Value = range1(RowNo).Value + range2(RowNo).Value + range3(RowNo).Value
Next RowNo

// return newRange
```

is this correct?

Comment: Why not just use the SUM formula?

Comment: It is a bigger vba code, and I cannot have the sums in the sheet, so I have to do it in VBA

Comment: As long as your ranges are aligned and the same size then this approach is perfectly fine.

Comment: don't I have to dimension newRange?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Option Explicit

Public Sub MakeRanges()

    Dim lngCounterLeft  As Long
    Dim lngCounterDown  As Long
    Dim lngCounter      As Long
    Dim rngCell         As Range
    Dim varResult       As Variant


    lngCounterDown = last_row(ActiveSheet.Name)
    lngCounterLeft = last_col(ActiveSheet.Name)
    ReDim varResult(0)

    For lngCounter = 1 To lngCounterDown
        Set rngCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(lngCounter, lngCounterLeft + 1)
        rngCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-" & lngCounterLeft & "]:RC[-1])"
        'rngCell.Interior.Color = vbRed

        If lngCounter > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve varResult(UBound(varResult) + 1)
        End If


        varResult(UBound(varResult)) = rngCell.Value
        rngCell.Clear

    Next lngCounter

    Stop

End Sub

Public Function last_row(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional column_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

    If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
        Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set shSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(str_sheet)
    End If

    last_row = shSheet.Cells(shSheet.Rows.Count, column_to_check).End(xlUp).Row

End Function

Public Function last_col(Optional str_sheet As String, Optional row_to_check As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim shSheet  As Worksheet

        If str_sheet = vbNullString Then
            Set shSheet = ActiveSheet
        Else
            Set shSheet = Worksheets(str_sheet)
        End If

    last_col = shSheet.Cells(row_to_check, shSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function
```

Run `MakeRanges`.
Pretty much, you receive a new column with the sum of the other columns.
It is a good idea to change the ActiveSheet into something meaningful. 
If you don't like the formula, you may uncomment the `rngCell.Value` in my code.
The array you need is `varResult`. Remove the `stop` and find a way to return it in a function.

Comment: Thanks! But I cannot populate the excel sheet. I need to keep the range in memory and return it in the function

Comment: I don't get it. You need to return just the range without any values? Or an array of those values - 6,11,4?

Comment: An array of the values 6, 11, and 4.. I just need to return something that can be used in a =SUM() function, so if I can just use a plain array, then it's fine